# HTML5 Download Attribute for image not working

Tags: html, download, attributes

Trying to get this file to be downloaded and renamed to "image.png", but every time I click on the download button, the file is always downloaded with the name: "leisa_christmas_false_color.png". Would appreciate any help, thanks.

```
<a id="download" href="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png" download="image.png">Download</a>
```

Comment: This can't be done on client side, You may do it on server.

Comment: @A.J What? I'm trying to inject code in developer tools to insert an A and the click it to download an image already on the page.  Why shouldn't *that* work???

Answer (score 0):

- Firefox only allows users to download files of the same origin due to a security concern. The file must come from your own server or domain name, otherwise it will be opened in the browser.
- While downloading cross-origin files is allowed in Chrome and the latest Opera (with Chromium/Blink), they will both ignore the attribute value. In other words, the file name will remain unchanged.

Don't use an extension like '.png' in the download attribute. You can't change the extension; it will be automaticly added.
Btw not every Browser actually support the download attribute. For more information take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: That has no effect when I test it

Comment: Which Browser are you using?

Comment: Tried removing the '.png' and it still had no effect. Also, I'm using Chrome, so it's fully supported.

Comment: Sounds strange. I'm using Chrome too and everything works fine, also this example: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download2

Comment: I guess the problem is that you try to "download" the image from a third party website. What happens if you use a relative link?

Comment: That's very weird, even using a relative link it STILL doesn't work.